# Haskell Platform vs homebrew

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I recently downloaded the Haskell Platform from the Haskell website. Under the suggestion of the newer answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709129/installing-haskell-packages-on-mac), I blindly ran `brew install ghc cabal-install` and `cabal install cabal cabal-install`. Did I install two versions of Haskell on my machine? What should I do to fix any problems?

Comment: the current platform is rather up-to-date I think so you probably just have installed ghc 7.10.2 in two different places so you are probably fine. Aside from this I cannot tell you more (I basically know nothing about Mac/Homebrew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily lead to problems to have multiple versions (I think I have three different versions installed). If you need the disk space uninstall one of the two ([instructions for the brew one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323261/uninstall-remove-a-homebrew-package-including-all-its-dependencies), for the packaged platform it seems you should be able to use the command `sudo uninstall-hs` but [check it yourself](https://wiki.haskell.org/Mac_OS_X) first). If you don't mind the lost disk space, you only have to make sure you have your `PATH` set up correctly, with the directory containing the ghc binary you want to use in your `PATH`, before the directory of the other one.

Also, `cabal install cabal-install` (which you might need to run to update cabal) tends to install cabal in a different place than the platform/brew do, so there, again, you need to make sure your `PATH` is appropriately set. Normally cabal installs executables in `~/.cabal/bin` (local installs) or `/usr/local/bin` (global installs). The directory containing `cabal` should go before the others, because an old version of `cabal` might stick around and you want the new one to be found first.

You probably know this but you can use `which ghc` and `which cabal` to check the location of the executable actually being used.

To make things even more complicated, lately it's popular to use [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack), which can also install ghc for you (I find this very convenient, everything is kept in a very controlled environment). So depending on your experience/use case this might be worth looking at as well (but if you just want to try Haskell I recommend you stick with the platform or the brew installation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just a couple minutes ago I had already uninstalled the brew version and HP and reinstalled HP. For future reference, how do I change the PATH variable?

Comment: @Nitin here's some good instructions: http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac

Comment: @Nitin you should either close the question or add your answer then